# Prove $(a, b) = (p_1)^{n_1}(p_2)^{n_2} \ldots (p_k)^{n_k}$ where for each $i, n_i = \min(r_i, s_i)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $a = (p_1)^{r_1}(p_2)^{r_2} \ldots (p_k)^{r_k}$ and $b = (p_1)^{s_1}(p_2)^{s_2} \ldots (p_k)^{s_k}$ where $p_i$ are distinct positive primes and each $r_i, s_i \ge 0$. Prove $(a, b) = (p_1)^{n_1}(p_2)^{n_2} \ldots (p_k)^{n_k}$ where for each $i, n_i = \min(r_i, s_i)$.

Let $(p_1)^{n_1}(p_2)^{n_2} \ldots (p_k)^{r_k} = c.$

If $r_i \le s_i$, then $c = a$. So, $c \mid a, b$.

If $r_i \ge s_i$, then $c = b$ and $c \mid b, a$.

So, $c$ is a common divisor of $a, b$. Does look like a convincing start?

Comment: No, because we may have $r_i\le s_i$  for some $i$s and $r_i>s_i$ for other $i$s.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case :)

Comment: But what is true is that $p_1^{n_1}\dotsm p_k^{n_k}$ is $\gcd(a,b)$. You must have learnt that in mid-school.

Comment: Sorry, I was a D-student in middle school.

Comment: Anyway, it was not proved, really. Another definition of $\gcd(a,b)$ is it's the positive generator of the ideal  $(a,b)$. So you have to prove $a$ and $b$ are both multiples of $c$, and conversely that $c$ is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Doing an example might clarify your thoughts a little bit: what is the greatest common divisor of $2^3\times3^2\times5\times7$ and $2\times3^2\times5^3$?

Comment: And for the general proof: to prove that some number $S$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$, you need to prove two things: first, that $S$ does indeed divide both $a$ and $b$; second, that $S$ is at least as large as any other common divisor of $a$ and $b$ (which in particular would follow from any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ also being a divisor of $S$). Can you prove either of these two statements?

Comment: @ Greg Martin, any prime $p_i$ to the power of $\min(r_i, s_i) $ divides $a, b, c$?

Comment: @GregMartin gcd will be minimum power of common primes in both of your numbers. but what to do to prove it rigorously ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $c:= p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}\ldots p_k^{n_k}$. It's sufficient to show that $c$ divides both $a$ and $b$ and that every common factor of $a$ and $b$ divides $c$ too.

Now,
$a = p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}\ldots p_k^{n_k}p_1^{r_1-n_1}p_2^{r_2-n_2}\ldots p_k^{r_k-n_k} = cp_1^{r_1-n_1}p_2^{r_2-n_2}\ldots p_k^{r_k-n_k}$, with $r_j - n_j \in \{0,1,...,r_j\}$ $\forall j \in \{1,2,...,k\}$ so that $p_1^{r_1-n_1}p_2^{r_2-n_2}\ldots p_k^{r_k-n_k}$ is an integer. Hence $c$ divides $a$. Similarly one shows that $c$ divides $b$. Conversely, suppose $c$ is positive integer which divides both $a$ and $b$. Then because $x$ can't have any prime factors but the $p_j$'s (why ?), every factor of $x$ must be of the form $p_1^{u_1}p_2^{u_2}\ldots p_k^{u_k}$, with $u_j \in \{0,1,...,\text{min}(r_j, s_j)\}$ for each $j$. Thus $x$ divides $c$. Therefore $c$ is precisely the g.c.d of $a$ and $b$.