# $lcm(a, b) = (p_1)^{t_1} (p_2)^{t_2} \ldots (p_k)^{t_k}$ where $t_i = \max(r_i, s_i) $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $a = (p_1)^{r_1} (p_2)^{r_2} \ldots (p_k)^{r_k}$ and $b = (p_1)^{s_1}  (p_2)^{s_2} \ldots (p_k)^{s_k}$ where $p_i$ are distinct positive primes and each $r_i, s_i \ge 0$.

Let $(p_1)^{t_1}  (p_2)^{t_2} \ldots (p_k)^{t_k}  = c$.

Since $t_i \ge s_i, r_i$, then $a, b \mid c$. Let $q$ be a prime distinct from any $p_i$. Then $a, b \mid cq$. Also, $c \mid cq$.

Does it work?

Comment: I suggest you reread your question and see if it makes any sense for someone who cannot read your mind.

Comment: @ Najib Idrissi, I need to prove what's in the title. The quoted bit contains the necessary assumptions. What's below the quote is my thoughts.

Comment: For a number to be a multiple of a second, it must contain at the very least the same prime factors. So, the least common multiple of two numbers will be that which contains the prime factors of both...i.e. the max powers of each prime from the two prime factorizations.

Comment: @ Winston, if $a \mid c,$ then $lcm (a, b) \mid c$. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can adapt the solution proposed for  a similar problem here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1424697/168758, and follow the reasoning.